# Tomcat Server quits working when GET and POST added to it

Tags: java, tomcat

for a project I have to make a Java backend using RESTful services, restservices. When I add a certain resource to my project with a get method and a post method, the server gives a 500 error. When i remove the GET and POST methods, it works fine again. Can anyone explain why it won't work?

Resource file:

```
package nl.hu.v1ipass.testipass.webservices; 

@Path("/aanmeldingen")
public class AanmeldingResource {
private JsonObjectBuilder aanmeldingToJson(Aanmelding aanmelding) {
    JsonObjectBuilder job = Json.createObjectBuilder();
    job.add("lidnummer", aanmelding.getEter().getLidNummer());
    job.add("lidnaam", aanmelding.getEter().getName());
    job.add("gerechtnaam", aanmelding.getGerecht().getName());

    return job;
}

@GET
@RolesAllowed("admin")
@Produces("appplication/json")
public String getAanmeldingen(@FormParam("datum") String datum) {
    AanmeldingService service = new AanmeldingService();        
    JsonArrayBuilder jab = Json.createArrayBuilder();

    for (Aanmelding a : service.getAanmeldingDate(datum)){ 
        jab.add(aanmeldingToJson(a));
    }

    JsonArray array = jab.build();
    return array.toString();
}

@POST
@RolesAllowed({"user", "admin"})
public Response addAanmelding(@FormParam("datum") String datum, @FormParam("gerecht") int gerechtId, @FormParam("lidnummer") int lidnummer) throws SQLException {
    AanmeldingService service = ServiceProvider.getAanmeldingService();     

    if(service.getAanmeldingDate(datum) == null) {
        Aanmelding returnAanmelding = service.addAanmelding(lidnummer, gerechtId);
        String a = aanmeldingToJson(returnAanmelding).build().toString();
        return Response.ok(a).build();
    } else {
        return Response.status(Response.Status.FOUND).build();
    }
}
}
```

UPDATE: with only the POST method, the server works fine. So what goes wrong in my GET method?

Comment: Can we see the stack trace in the server logs?

Comment: FormParam on a GET doesn't make sense: GET requests don't have a body.

Comment: Hmm you're right! But then how can I get the date from a HTML form into this method?

Comment: Could you please post the tomcat log ?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```
@Produces("appplication/json")
```

to

```
@Produces("application/json")
```

notice the spelling mistake